# Find dict elems based on its key n-elemnt tuple's condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose `keys` are tuples of length *n*.

For example, for *n = 3*:

```
{('I', 'like', 'you'): 14, ('you', 'like', 'it'): 12, ('he', 'likes', 'it'): 2}
```

I can find all words for key tuples that end with a given word, like this:

```
word = 'it'
words = [rest[-1] for first, *rest in counted_ngrams if rest[-1] == word]
```

But, how to make **a dictionary** of complete (tuple + number) elements from the original dictionary whose keys ends with a given word, e.g., `'it'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a handy dictionary-comprehension like so:

```
a = {('I', 'like', 'you'): 14, ('you', 'like', 'it'): 12, ('he', 'likes', 'it'): 2}

b = {k: v for k, v in a.items() if k[-1] == 'it'}
print(b)  # -> {('you', 'like', 'it'): 12, ('he', 'likes', 'it'): 2}
```

Checking for `k[-1]` instead of `k[2]` ensures the above works with tuples of any length (even inconsistent lengths).